# Unable to convert StreamingResponseBody streams into JSON using JavaScript's ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, java, json, parsing

The back-end API sends streams (of JSON) using Java's StreamingResponseBody. I want to convert the chunks of the streams into proper JSON format using javascript (at front-end). However, it is not working. Here is the code I used:

```
function getData () {
 fetch("MY_URL")
   .then(response=>{
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      return new ReadableStream({
         start(controller) {
            return pump();
            function pump() {
              return reader.read().then({done, value}) => {
                  if(done){
                     controller.close();
                     console.log("Done");
                     return;
                  }
                  const chunk = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
                  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chunk)));

                  controller.enqueue(value);
                  return pump();
              });
            }
         }
      });
     }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

How can I fix it so it can convert the chunks into JSON?

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: It simply shows an HTML page. I think the conversion JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chunk)) doesn't seem to work. Is this the correct way to convert the chunk?